# Redirecionar quando tiver um evento de clique na página

Tags: javascript

Quero redirecionar de uma página para outra quando o usuário efetuar um clique nela, independente do lugar, porém, não estou conseguindo

`$.onclick.(function() {
    window.location.href = "http://...";
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar **"vanilla js"** sem necessidade de um framework, basta adicionar um ouvinte ao evento "clique" no documento e usar `.replace()` no objeto `window.location` ... veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.location.replace('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/')
}, false)
```

---

Mas se prefierir usar **jQuery**, podes mapear o documento pela tag `<html>` mesmo:

```js
$('html').on('click', function(evt) {
    window.location.replace('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Fontes:

- [Location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)
- [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Coloque um "ID" em seu body, e faça o seguinte.

```
$("#idBody").on("click" function() {
    window.location.assign("http://pt.stackoverflow.com");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa passar a instrução `body` para o seu `jQuery` afim de dizer qual o tipo de elemento que receberá o `listener`:

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {
    window.location.href = "http://...";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```